# Are there any keyboard shortcuts in R to replace variable names with new names while writing a code?

Tags: r

In the below-stated code, I wanted to replace all the variables named "sh" with "sh1" for only selected lines of codes instead of the entire one. Instead of Find and replace, is there any keyboard shortcuts for that in R ?

## Old code

```
(cp.table.sh<-shop.rp[["cptable"]])
cp.ix.sh<-which.min(cp.table.sh[,"xerror"])
print(cp.table.sh[cp.ix.sh,])
cp.min.sh<-cp.table.sh[cp.ix.sh,"CP"]
```

## Modified code

```
(cp.table.sh1<-shop.rp[["cptable"]])
```

`cp.ix.sh1<-which.min(cp.table.sh1[,"xerror"])`
`print(cp.table.sh1[cp.ix.sh1,])`

```
cp.min.sh1<-cp.table.sh1[cp.ix.sh1,"CP"]
```

Comment: `RStudio` has a good find and replace feature. Use` CTRL+F`. LMK if this works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `RStudio` there is a keyboard short cut to Rename in Scope `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+M`. Just need to highlight the variable you are looking to replace first.